# How would I select this dropdown item labeled 'Geschlecht' with a CSS Selector in Selenium?

Tags: python, selenium, css-selectors

There are multiple elements with class `select2-selection select2-selection--single` on my page.

How would I select the dropdown item with the class mentioned and filter the one with the accompanying label 'Geschlecht', see screenshot? I would prefer using a CSS Selector instead of a XPATH
[image]

Answer (score 0):

I would use xpath in this instance because "Geschlecht" is text. `//label[text()= "Geschlecht"]` If this doesn't work let me know and we can come up with a more complicated xpath.

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. My preferred solution would be with a CSS Selector. However, since there are multiple `select2-selection select2-selection--single` classes on the page, I would like to come up with a CSS Selector that chooses the class mentioned and selects the one with the accompanying label 'Geschlecht'.